# Woodbury matrix inversion prove

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

I'm trying to solve Woodbury matrix inversion to prove the correctness of this result.

\begin{align}
&(A+UCV)
\left(A^{-1}-A^{-1}U(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}\right)=\\
&=AA^{-1}-AA^{-1}U(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}+UCVA^{-1}-UCVA^{-1}U(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1} \\
&=I-U(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}+UCVA^{-1}+U(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}-UCVA^{-1} \\
&=I
\end{align}
I don't understand the next step:
\begin{align}
-UCVA^{-1}U(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}&=-UC(-C^{-1}+C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1} \\ &=U(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}-UCVA^{-1}.
\end{align}

I've tried to understand this: [Comment from a partner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSU77.png)

But I only understood this: From the first summand, the two minus signs cancel and
\begin{align} UCC^{-1}=U. \end{align}, so you get 
\begin{align}
U(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}.
\end{align}

(English is not my native language, apology and thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$-UC(-C^{-1}+C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1} = \\ 
=(-UC)(-C^{-1})(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1} + (-UC)(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}=\\
=U(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}-UCVA^{-1}$

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much. I'd give you more points but I can't. Now I understand the first partner (I think he's missing a +). Thanks to him too